# How can I get this App Store purchase window in my app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have implemented subscription IAP in my iOS app, but now my boss showed me several apps that provide a very nice purchase ActionSheet like window, when purchasing:

[image: Nice IAP window]

I only get simple Alerts that confirm purchase.

[image]

Is this a custom library? I see it in several apps, so it doesn't seem to be a pure custom design. Would love to use it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first image (The nice User Interface) of yours is from the latest iOS version (**iOS 11**). That screen gets displayed when you make a purchase in **iOS 11**. Previous versions will show you the second image for purchases. Get an iOS 11 device and go to App Store to download an app, and you'll get that new fancy UI.

To get that new UI, the app must be compiled with iOS 11 SDK.

Comment: Ok, interesting. However, I tested my app on iOS 11, but did not get such a fancy user interface. Maybe it needs to be build using XCode 9?

Comment: What have you used to display the In-App purchase page?

Comment: `var payment = SKMutablePayment(product: subscription.product)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)`

Comment: I tried building it in Xcode 9 but I still get the Alerts instead of that nice sheet interface. I read somewhere that the old interface gets shown when using sandbox purchases, so I assume it will display normally on release app.

Comment: This new iOS 11 sheet is shown here: (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/303/ around 8:30)

Comment: Yeah. That’s right. That will be showing up in your production app.